# Passing values dynamically from config file to SQL query in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I have developed a SSIS Package in which I am using a SQL task. The `.SQL` file is being picked up from a particular folder in my file system. My SQL Script is creating a database and creating some SQL logins.

I need to pass the username/login name dynamically through config file in my `.SQL` file.

```
CREATE USER [userneme/login name] FOR LOGIN [userneme/login name ] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [userneme/login name ]
GO
```

The SQL Task Property **SQLSourceType** has been set as FileConnection.
How can I pass these values dynamically? I am already reading connection string from config file.

Comment: can you post the format of your sql file?

Comment: SQL File Looks like:                                                                                                               USE [databasename]
GO
/****** Object:  User [userneme/login name]    Script Date: 15/09/2016 14:03:40 ******/
CREATE USER [userneme/login name] FOR LOGIN [userneme/login name] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
CREATE USER [userneme/login name] FOR LOGIN [userneme/login name] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO

Answer (score 0):

You can set up your input file as a CSV, and loop through the rows, and execute a script one row at a time.